# bash background process not working, or am I missing something?

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

I have written a script to split my pdf files between pages I give, and compress them using `gs` and then output it to a pdf file.
I want to run my script in the background, but am I missing something? I should use `&` at the end of line, but it still prints output. so I use:

```
./gs 12 20 temp > /dev/null &
```

but it just goes to the background and I should use `fg` to run it actually.
so what is it I am missing? `&` should send the process to background but it stops at background. I want it to run in background.

**edit:**

problem is solved. it was my mistake to look for wrong file the script creates.

it works like a charm!

Comment: your script expecting input from stdin?

Comment: no, it just works. no stdin input or stdout output is needed.

Comment: I have to ask: Have you confirmed that it works as intended without the `&`?

Comment: I'd use strace to see what it's waiting for.

Comment: How are you confirming that it is *not* running in the background?

Comment: here is the output of command mentioned: `[1] 9324`

Comment: and the script works in a normal call (without ` > /dev/null & ` )

Comment: found out the problem, it was my mistake! sorry

i just didnt look for the right file it creates, and i thought it was not running. again i am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is from your shell. When you background a job, it prints the job id `[1]` and the process id `9324` so that you have a way to manipulate your background jobs. It indicates that the job is in fact running in the background.

To bring it back to the foreground, `fg %1` (to refer to the job id, use a percent sign) or to kill it, `kill 9324`.